# Observable subscribe not fired

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following snippet:

```
static groupAlphabetically<T>(observable:Observable<T[]>): Observable<AlphabeticalGroup<T>[]>{
return (observable.pipe(
  switchMap(data => data as T[]), 
  reduce((r, e:T) => {
    let group = e["name"][0] as string;
    var currentGroup = r.filter(x => x.letter == group)[0];
    if(!currentGroup) 
    {
      currentGroup = new AlphabeticalGroup<T>();
      currentGroup.letter = group;
      r.push(currentGroup);
    }

    currentGroup.items.push(e);
    return r;
  }, new Array<AlphabeticalGroup<T>>())
  ));
}
```

For some reason, this piped observable never finishes. 
What am I doing wrong?
When debugging, I can step onto the return r statement, but subscribing never works:

```
subscribe(x => {
// this code is never reached
})
```

Comment: Hey @Malaf. You should return an `Observable` from inside a `switchMap` operator. If you want to consume data as an array in the following `reduce` oprator, try adding `switchMap(data => of(data))` instead of your `switchMap`, `of` will produce the new `Observable`

Comment: Hi @nahkodjin, this doesn't work either. The parsing of the alphabetical group array seems to work, however, any following subcribe or other map/swith map seem to fail.

Comment: By "parsing of the alphabetical group" you mean that the code within the `reduce` operator gets executed?

Comment: Yes exactly, but subscribing to the result does not work. (It never gets triggered).
The if I use a map after the reduce, then that map isn't called either.

Answer (score 0):

switchMap does not expand the Array so in your reduce function e != T but e =T[].
Use the groupBy operator in RxJS.

See [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vphehq) below

```
export const groupAlphabetical = (observable: Observable<hasName[]>) => observable.pipe(
      flatMap(x => x),
      groupBy(x => x.name[0],x=> x),
      mergeMap( (group$) => group$.pipe(reduce((acc, cur) =>{
          acc.items = [...acc.items, cur];
          return acc;
      }, {
        letter: group$.key,
        items:[]
      })))
    );
```

hasName interface :

```
export interface hasName {
  name: string;
}
```